# ColdFusion cfif evaluation inside a string

Tags: coldfusion

I have a link that recalls the same page with some variables but I want to send one of the variables only if the condition is satisfied.

```
<a href="testing.cfm?"<cfif checkMonth>"theday=#theday#&"</cfif>"themonth=#themonth#&theyear=#theyear#&checkMonth=#checkMonth#">
```

This is the code. 
I would prefer not to write 2 lines for each condition. It might not be possible but I just wanted to ask.

Comment: Skip the quotes (like Matt said) - you may also need `<cfoutput>#variables.theday#</cfoutput>` unless you are already inside of an output.

Answer (score 1):

You're adding unnecessary `"` to the string. Once you remove those the following should work.

```
<a href="testing.cfm?<cfif checkMonth>theday=#theday#&</cfif>themonth=#themonth#&theyear=#theyear#&checkMonth=#checkMonth#">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write
`<a href="testing.cfm?<cfif checkMonth>theday=#theday#&</cfif>themonth=#themonth#&theyear=#theyear#&checkMonth=#checkMonth#">`

Answer (score -2):

You could do something like this:

```
urlVariables = "dummyVariable=1";
urlVariables &= condition goes here ? "&Variable="#something#" : "";
etc

<a href="somewhere.cfm?#urlVariables#">link</a>
```